# Difference between normal function and IIFE that turn another function

Tags: javascript

My code is like this:

Example 1:

```
var fn = (function () {
    function fn (a, b, c) {
        /* CODE HERE */
    };

    return fn;

})();

fn(a, b, c);
```

Example 2:

```
var fn = function fn (a, b, c) {};
fn(a, b, c);
```

what is the difference between this two calls? I'm trying to refact some codes. When i try to put out the fn function like the second example, it fails.

Comment: You can have **private** methods and data in IIFE

Comment: If the second method fails, it fails because of something else in the code. In other words, explainging the difference between these two functions won't help you *at all* because it won't solve your actual problem. Please show your *actual* code, or at least an example that's so close to the actual code that we can see the real problem.

Answer (score 4):

The most common use case for IIFE is to create a closure with some **private** variables inside of it. For example:

```
var counter = (function() {
    // This variable is private. You cannot change it from the outer code.
    var i = 0;

    return function() {
        return i++;
    };
})();

console.log(counter());
console.log(counter());
console.log(counter());
```

outputs:

```
0
1
2
```

So, when you refactor IIFE to regular functions you have to make sure that you deal with closures in the right way.